# Can multiple regression be used to test individual hypotheses?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons, familywise-error

In the linked article [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.02947) Rubin proposes that familywise error correction is not necessary when the hypotheses are either that all tests will be significant ('conjunction testing') or that a series of individual tests, each with its own hypothesis, will be significant ('individual testing'), and is only necessary when the hypotheses is that *any* of several tests will be significant ('disjunction testing').

I am curious whether multiple regression, where you are testing the association between multiple covariates on a single outcome in a single model, is *always* a case of disjunction testing or whether it could be considered a case of individual testing within a single model?